# Pulling a head record in s3 command but resulting in ^M

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I tried to run below command

`aws s3 cp s3://path/to/my/object - | head` and when I try to put into a variable and use it its having a ^M in the last

I tried to `$(echo "$TMP_FIELDS_LIST"|tr -d '\n')` even though I can see ^M in the last of the variable.

`TMP_FIELDS_LIST=aws s3 cp s3://path/to/my/object - | head`

`` FIELDS_LIST=`$(echo "$TMP_FIELDS_LIST"|tr -d '\n') ``

when I use `$FIELDS_LIST` in my code I am getting ^M in the last

Comment: If you want to remove the `^M` character, please try `FIELD_LIST=$(echo "$TMP_FIELDS_LIST" | tr -d '\r')` or `FIELD_LIST=$(tr -d '\r' <<< "$TMP_FIELDS_LIST")`.

Comment: Does the `aws` command without `head` works fine?

Comment: @tshiono - using both is making the variable null.

Comment: @Fazlin I am able to echo $TMP_FIELDS_LIST after the ```TMP_FIELDS_LIST=aws s3 cp s3://path/to/my/object - | head``` I am able to see headers

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to get the head values from a csv file from s3 file and put into a variable and use it in my shell script.